# Magento 2. Does Commerce offers more functionality than Open Source in term of Web APIs?

Tags: magento2, web-services, webapi

Does Magento 2 Commerce offer something in addition to what M2 Open Source offers in terms of Web APIs?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, Core WebAPI Structure for both `Magento 2 Commerce` and `Magento 2 open Source` is same but `Magento 2 Commerce` is more optimized in terms of scalability, security.

All the Modules that are available in both `Magento 2 Commerce` and `Magento 2 open Source`, have the Same API. As you can check using the below links:

> [List of REST APIs for Magento Open Source and Magento Commerce](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/list.html#list)

But as we all know that Magento Commerce provide so many extra fetures as well like: Reward Point, RMA, GiftCard etc. So API is available for this modules as well:

> [List of REST endpoints for Magento Commerce](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.2/rest/list.html#listee)

I checked the Magento Commerce feaure list and found this:

- Leverage sample code to quickly create an Apple iOS 8+ app using Magento 2.0 APIs

Comment: Thank you for answer. I'm leaving it unaccepted for the moment to see if some more answers come up